# Targeting android from own language

Tags: android, compiler-construction, dalvik

I have my own language that compiles to assembly and gets executed on Intel machines.

Now I want to target Android devices so I can write my programs with my language and get them executed on Android.

My compiler supports adding new target machine codes so what do you think the best way to go about this?

- Do I target Java byte code and then convert it to dalvik?
- Is it possible to target dalvik dex format?
- Any better/easier solutions?